Validating input in tkinter
I am very very new to Python (about 2 weeks). I am writing a GUI using tkinter. The interface has 3 frames. In one frame I enter data and use it to do simple calculations. I would like to test for valid input. However, the compiler requires me to assign the input data type before the code will run. I have defined my variables as DoubleVar as I want to work with float. When I try and validate the input, the code works if I input numbers but obviously doesnt work if I type a string. Trying to test the input data type from within the function doesnt work as the function sees the data as a float. Any ideas - should be a simple problem.The function is called from a button
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import messagebox
win=tk.Tk()
ucs_var=tk.DoubleVar()    # define ucs input value as a float
block_var=tk.DoubleVar()  # defines block size as a float`

# The following function deals with a button that gets data from Entry widget

def calculation():   # Handles calculation button click

    if type(ucs_var.get())==float or type(ucs_var.get())==int:
       ucs=ucs_var.get()
       block_size=block_var.get()
       velocity =float(ucs*0.027+2.63)  #convert string to float  
       velocity_float= "{:.{}f}".format(velocity,2)       #format velocity to 2    decimal places
       result_label.config(text=velocity_float)
       block_size=block_var.get()
       energy=float(0.5*block_size*pow(velocity,2))
       energy_float= "{:.{}f}".format(energy,1)
       energy_label.config(text=energy_float)
    else: 
       print("Data input error")
       return


Simple workaround is:

user StringVar() instead of DoubleVar()
use try / except to catch invalid inputs

Below is the modified code:
...

ucs_var = tk.StringVar()   # use StringVar instead of DoubleVar
block_var = tk.StringVar()

# The following function deals with a button that gets data from Entry widget

def calculation():   # Handles calculation button click
    try:
        ucs = float(ucs_var.get())  # convert input to float
        block_size = float(block_var.get())

        velocity = ucs * 0.027 + 2.63
        velocity_float = round(velocity, 2)  # round to 2 decimal places
        result_label.config(text=velocity_float)

        energy = 0.5 * block_size * pow(velocity, 2)
        energy_float= round(energy, 1)  # round to 1 decimal place
        energy_label.config(text=energy_float)
    except Exception as ex:
       print("Data input error:", ex)

...


Thank you very much- it worked perfectly

@StephenWebber If it works, consider to accept it as answer and upvote.
